# Why is c++ template argument deduction failing in this case?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, delegates, function-pointers

I am trying to write my own delegate system as a replacement for boost::functions since the latter does a lot of heap-allocations which I profiled to be problematic.
I have written this as a replacement (simplified, the actual thing uses pooled memory and placement new but this is simple enough to reproduce the error):

```
template<class A, class B>
struct DelegateFunctor : public MyFunctor {
  DelegateFunctor(void (*fptr)(A, B), A arg1, B arg2) : fp(fptr), a1(arg1), a2(arg2) {}

  virtual void operator()() { fp(a1, a2); }

  void (*fp)(A, B);  // Stores the function pointer.
  const A a1; const B a2;  // Stores the arguments.
};
```

and this helper function:

```
template<class A, class B>
MyFunctor* makeFunctor(void (*f)(A,B), A arg1, B arg2) {
  return new DelegateFunctor<A,B>(f, arg1, arg2);
}
```

The weird thing happens here:

```
void bar1(int a, int b) {
  // do something
}

void bar2(int& a, const int& b) {
  // do domething
}

int main() {
  int a = 0;
  int b = 1;

  // A: Desired syntax and compiles.
  MyFunctor* df1 = makeFunctor(&bar1, 1, 2);

  // B: Desired syntax but does not compile:
  MyFunctor* df2 = makeFunctor(&bar2, a, b);

  // C: Not even this:
  MyFunctor* df3 = makeFunctor(&bar2, (int&)a, (const int&)b);

  // D: Compiles but I have to specify the whole damn thing:
  MyFunctor* df4 = makeFunctor<int&, const int&>(&bar2, a, b);
}
```

The compiler error I get for version C (B is similar) is:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘makeFunctor(void (*)(int&, const int&), int&, const int&)’
```

which is weird because the compiler has, in its error message, in fact correctly deduced the types.
Is there any way I can get version B to compile? How does boost::bind get around this limitation?
I'm using GCC 4.2.1. No C++11 solutions please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Argument deduction strips off references. By matching the function pointer signature for `A`, we want to get `int &`, but by matching the actual argument, we want `int`, and so the deduction fails.

One solution is to make the second type non-deduced, like so:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename R, typename A, typename B>
R do_it(R (*func)(A, B),
        typename std::common_type<A>::type a,   // not deduced
        typename std::common_type<B>::type b)   // not deduced
{
    return func(a, b);
}
```

Now `A` and `B` are determined purely by the function pointer's signature:

```
int foo(int &, int const &);

int main()
{
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    return do_it(foo, a, b);  // deduces A = int &, B = int const &
}
```

<sub>(Note that `std::common_type<T>::type` is the recommended idiom for the "identity type" whose sole purpose is to remove a template argument from argument deduction. This has previously been called things like `identity<T>::type` or `alias<T>`, but the standard library trait `std::common_type` serves this purpose just fine.)</sub>

Comment: The <type_traits> header seems to be a C++11 header but I just wrote my own IdentityType thing which works fine. Nice answer, thanks much!

Comment: @RafaelSpring: Yes, prior to C++11 people used to roll their own identity wrappers. Good stuff. And for completeness, in C++11 some people like to use `template <typename T> using alias = T;`, but this has yet to grow on me.

Answer (score 2):

When deducing template arguments using a value argument, you will only ever get a value type. That is, when you using a function template like

```
template <typename T>
void f(T) {
}
```

the type `T` will always be a non-reference type. Now, when you try to pass a function pointer and a value, the compiler has no way to make the deduced types to be consistent if the function does not take a value type:

```
template <typename T>
void f(void (*)(T), T) {}

void f0(int);
void f1(int const&);

int main() {
    f(&f0, 0); // OK
    f(&f1, 0); // ERROR
}
```

One way to deal with this problem is to appropriately overload the corresponding function template. If you add the function below to the mix the above example works again:

```
template <typename T>
void f(void (*)(T const&), T const&) {}
```

Clearly, this become quickly a maintenance nightmare and is probably **not** what you want to do. The alternative is to use different template parameters for the respective arguments:

```
template <typename T, typename S>
void f(void (*)(T), S) {}
```

Although this works, this has the immediate impact that you don't necessarily match the type you really want to match for the second argument: it will be a value type even though you might want to get a reference type (personally, I doubt you do but this is a different issue). If you don't want this to happen, you can prevent the compiler form trying to deduce the arguments for some of the argument. For example:

```
template <typename T>
struct helper {
    typedef T type;
};
template <typename T>
void f(void (*)(T), typename helper<T>::type) {}
```

Although the above example just demonstrate the issue at hand using just one template argument, I'm sure this works with more template arguments as well. Whether this is what Boost does I neither know nor care.

Comment: Please explain: Why wouldn't I want to pass values by reference through a delegate interface like this?

Comment: In most case you don't want to call the function immediately but at some later point. Using `T const&` for these parameter will very likely cause them to have gone away. For `T&` you might indeed want to use them directly but even then is binding them implicitly quite error prone.